# What is the SourceMapDevToolPlugin configuration equivalent for devtool:cheap-module-eval-source-map

Tags: webpack, source-maps

Are there are any examples of how to configure [SourceMapDevToolPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/source-map-dev-tool-plugin/) to match the various devtool sourcemap options.

For example, what is the SourceMapDevToolPlugin configuration equivalent for `devtool:cheap-module-eval-source-map`
I'm trying to configure the plugin to map the various options for [devtool](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#devtool).

Answer (score 4):

For posterity (I was looking for this too):

I think the OP is looking for `EvalSourceMapDevToolPlugin` which is the plugin for eval-sourcemap functionality. The equivalent should be:

```
new webpack.EvalSourceMapDevToolPlugin({ columns: false });
```

reference documentation: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/eval-source-map-dev-tool-plugin/